# Create pdf using cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, pdf-generation

There is some tutorial about how to create a pdf using cocoa? I can't find anything. I looked for it on the web and it seems that I need Quartz to do it, but there aren't  practical examples.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

—Albé

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Cocoa Printing Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Concepts/architecture.html) documentation.  Basically, any printing operation creates a PDF and, in general, the best way to create PDF documents is to implement custom printing layouts.

Alternatively, [NSView](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) has printing related methods for grabbing the PDF within a rectangle.