# Cocoa swift macOS Print html to pdf

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf, printing, swift4

I want to generate a pdf file from html content. (To generate invoices from a html template)
I would like to note, that I am a **swift-beginner**.

To print the html content to a pdf file I use the following code:

```
func makePDF(markup: String) {
    let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    
    let printOpts: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey: Any] = [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobDisposition: NSPrintInfo.JobDisposition.save, NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobSavingURL: directoryURL]
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printOpts)
    //printInfo.horizontalPagination = NSPrintInfo.
    //printInfo.verticalPagination = NSPrintInfo.AutoPagination
    printInfo.topMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 20.0
    
    let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 570, height: 740))
    
    if let htmlData = markup.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        if let attrStr = NSAttributedString(html: htmlData, options: [ .documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            
            print(attrStr);
        
            let frameRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 570, height: 740)
            let textField = NSTextField(frame: frameRect)
            textField.attributedStringValue = attrStr
            view.addSubview(textField)
            
            let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: view, printInfo: printInfo)
            

            printOperation.showsPrintPanel = false
            printOperation.showsProgressPanel = false
            printOperation.run()
        }
    }
```

Which is based on this StackOverFlow Question/Answer : [StackOverFlowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022707/7274172)

I had to "translate" the code to swift4 - Any mistakes here are very possible
When running the code I get the following logs (in that order):

1. NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
2. Printing failed because PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog() returned -61.
3. NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog() -61 -> means that I don't have the permission to write at a certain location according to [this](http://krypted.com/lists/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/) (Write permission error)

I tried to switch of the sandbox mode, and gave the application the right to read and write to/from desktop files.

Does any one know how to fix the PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog() -61 error?
(or in general get the code up and running...)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more research brought up the following answer:
[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479101/7274172)

which refers to this GitHub project
[GitHub Swift 3 PDFCreator](https://github.com/owlswipe/CocoaPDFCreator)

The code in the github project solved my errors! Worked perfectly.